# How to format column widths in table to prevent table entering right margin

Tags: tables, positioning, columns

I have a table that is displaying like this:

[image]

And I wonder if anyone can help in realigning the column widths so that the table does not enter the right margin of the page.

I am quite happy for the header of the first column to wrap onto the second line of the table's header.

A minimum working example (with many unnecessary `\usepackage` lines) follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\marginsize{3.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}

\begin{document}

This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Days of month}} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Segment}} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{3}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{6}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{7}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{8}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{9}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10}} \\

        \midrule
        04 - 06 & Train & \textcolor{red}{Test} & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Schedule.}
\end{table}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The bunch of `lllllllllll` specifiers can be reduced to `*{11}l` which is considerably shorter

Comment: The few columns in the table will contain words like `train` or `test` and I tried the table with `p{1cm}` but had trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\marginsize{3.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}
\begin{document}

This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

\begin{table}
    \small\centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{11}c}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Month}} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Segment}} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{days}} &
        \textbf{1}  &
        \textbf{2}  &
        \textbf{3}  &
        \textbf{4}  &
        \textbf{5}  &
        \textbf{6}  &
        \textbf{7}  &
        \textbf{8}  &
        \textbf{9}  &
        \textbf{10} \\ \midrule
        04 - 06 & Train & \textcolor{red}{Test} & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train & Train \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Schedule.}
\end{table}   

\end{document}
```

You can use a smaller font. At `12pt`, setting a `\small` text size for the table text will not be very noticeable. Also the heading can be adapted to break over two lines perhaps with rephrasing to make it shorter. Finally, all `\multicolumn{1}{c}` for segment entries are not needed and using `*{11}c` is more compact and appropriate.

Also, `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` is not needed as of 2015 because all fixes to LaTeX2e are now part of the base distribution.

Comment: Although it would be good if the numeric column headings could be centre aligned.

Comment: @MrMorgan  -- They are already centered. `*{11}c` is there for doing this.

Comment: My mistake. I mean the column text, not the headings.

Comment: Yes, all table entries are centered except `Month` and `days` which are left aligned.

Comment: Given the table as it is, can the text of the columns be left aligned with the headings being centered?

Comment: Yes, remove `*{11}c` and put `*{11}l`, then with headings only use `\multicolumn{<num>}{c}{<heading text>}`. As an example `\multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Segment}}`.

Comment: I find that that will left align the headings and the column values.